# R loop that adds following numbers to each element in list

Tags: r, loops

I would like to create a loop that adds the following two numbers to each element in the list. This means that from a list with a random sequence of number like:

> z
>    [1]  70   2  14 107  50  90  15  44  77  97  64

This loop would create

> z
>    [1]  70 71 72  2 3 4 14 15 16 107 108 109 110 50 51 52 90 91 92 15 16 17 44 45 46 77 78 79 97 98 99 64 65 66

Sorry for my bad example and thank you in advance for your help. Feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: please consider to accept Akrun's comprehend answer. Click the check mark next to the vote. Your question will then be marked as solved too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

We can loop over the vector, get a sequence of `:` of values from that element to the next two

```
c(sapply(z, function(x) x:(x+2)))
#[1]  70  71  72   2   3   4  14  15  16 107 108 109  50  51  52  90  91  92  15  16  17  44  45  46  77  78  79  97  98  99  64  65  66
```

---

Or with `replicate`

```
c(t(replicate(3, z)) + 0:2)
#[1]  70  71  72   2   3   4  14  15  16 107 108 109  50  51  52  90  91  92  15  16  17  44  45  46  77  78  79  97  98  99  64  65  66
```

---

Or with `outer`

```
c(t(outer(z, 0:2, `+`)))
#[1]  70  71  72   2   3   4  14  15  16 107 108 109  50  51  52  90  91  92  15  16  17  44  45  46  77  78  79  97  98  99  64  65  66
```

---

Or with `expand.grid`

```
with(expand.grid(0:2, z), Var1 + Var2)
```

#### data

```
z <- c(70, 2, 14, 107, 50, 90, 15, 44, 77, 97, 64)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is `rep`

```
rep(z, each = 3) + 0:2
# [1]  70  71  72   2   3   4  14  15  16 107 108 109  50  51  52  90
#[17]  91  92  15  16  17  44  45  46  77  78  79  97  98  99  64  65
#[33]  66
```

**benchmark**

```
library(bench)
set.seed(42)
n <- 1e6
z <- sample(seq_len(n))
mark(
  akrun1 = c(sapply(z, function(x) x:(x+2))),
  akrun2 = c(t(replicate(3, z)) + 0:2),
  akrun3 = c(t(outer(z, 0:2, `+`))),
  akrun4 = with(expand.grid(0:2, z), Var1 + Var2),
  tmfmnk = unlist(Map(seq, z, z + 2)),
  markus = rep(z, each = 3) + 0:2, iterations = 15
)
# A tibble: 6 x 13
#  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result  memory   time   gc    
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>  <list>   <list> <list>
#1 akrun1        1.48s    2.45s     0.427    57.6MB    2.22     15    78     35.09s <int [~ <Rprofm~ <bch:~ <tibb~
#2 akrun2      19.41ms  20.71ms    19.5      45.8MB    9.10     15     7   768.94ms <int [~ <Rprofm~ <bch:~ <tibb~
#3 akrun3       31.3ms  43.96ms    25.1      57.2MB   15.1      15     9   597.13ms <int [~ <Rprofm~ <bch:~ <tibb~
#4 akrun4        1.18s    1.46s     0.670    91.6MB    0.760    15    17     22.37s <int [~ <Rprofm~ <bch:~ <tibb~
#5 tmfmnk        7.93s     8.6s     0.111    26.7MB    3.17     15   428      2.25m <int [~ <Rprofm~ <bch:~ <tibb~
#6 markus      54.85ms  69.69ms    10.7      11.4MB    0.713    15     1       1.4s <int [~ <Rprofm~ <bch:~ <tibb~
```

Comment: +1, the interesting thing to me is how memory efficient it is. I did a for loop as well as a ```Rcpp``` for loop and had the same memory allocation. While not surprising, compiled ```Rcpp``` code was faster but probably not worth it - yours is super fast and efficient.

Comment: @Cole Thanks mate. Why not post the rcpp solution here too? You'd have my vote. Best

Answer (score 1):

One option could be:

```
unlist(Map(seq, x, x + 2))

 [1]  70  71  72   2   3   4  14  15  16 107 108 109  50  51  52  90  91  92  15  16  17  44
[23]  45  46  77  78  79  97  98  99  64  65  66
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to do an explicit loop. That is, for each value in `z`, we want to add each value from the second vector `0:2`.

```
for_loop = function(z1, z2) {
  ans = integer(length(z1) * length(z2))
  ind = 1L
  for (i in z1) {
    for (j in z2) {
      ans[ind] = i + j
      ind = ind + 1L
    }
  }
  return(ans)
}

z = as.integer(c(70, 2, 14, 107, 50, 90, 44, 77, 97, 64))
for_loop(z, 0:2)

## [1]  70  71  72   2   3   4  14  15  16 107 108 109  50  51  52  90  91
## [18]  92  44  45  46  77  78  79  97  98  99  64  65  66
```

The nice thing of using a loop is that if you are in need of performance, it is typically easy to convert to `Rcpp`. The code is very similar but we need to declare our variables and have to use 0-based indexing instead of 1-based indexing:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction(
"IntegerVector Rcpp_for_loop(IntegerVector z1, IntegerVector z2) {
 const int n_z1 = z1.size();
 const int n_z2 = z2.size();
 IntegerVector ans(n_z1 * n_z2);
 int ind = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < n_z1; i++) {
  int tmp = z1[i];
  for (int j = 0; j < n_z2; j++) {
    ans[ind++] = tmp + z2[j];
  }
 }
 return(ans);
}")
```

Using @markus setup these are the `bench::mark(...)` results, mainly provided because of pointing out how short the code @markus used was while being as memory efficient as an `Rcpp` solution.

```
##  loop = for_loop(z, 0:2),
##  Rcpp_loop = Rcpp_for_loop(z, 0:2)

### A tibble: 8 x 13
##  expression     min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
##  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
##1 akrun1       2.18s    2.18s    0.458     53.8MB
##2 akrun2     32.24ms 152.25ms    5.93      45.8MB
##3 akrun3     47.91ms  69.34ms   13.2       57.2MB
##4 akrun4       1.14s    1.14s    0.880     83.9MB
##5 tmfmnk      11.68s   11.68s    0.0856    22.9MB
##6 markus     24.03ms  24.48ms   16.8       11.4MB
##7 loop         1.06s    1.06s    0.939     11.4MB
##8 Rcpp_loop   5.53ms   5.81ms  120.        11.4MB
```